# How to reduce and compress an apk file in android

Tags: android

I have one apk file but its file size is 22.4 MB. It's huge, so I need to reduce or compress the apk file in android. What is the right way to reduce and compress the apk file size?

Comment: did you have use images in your APK

Comment: Could you explain how it contain 22.4 MB?

Comment: apk is like zip file.if you change .apk to .zip you can extract it.so if you need less size you should remove .mp3 or .png or ... from your files or assets.because file in assets become in apk as is

Comment: to reduce you need to remove unnecessary images from your drawable folder unecessary assest or any files from assest folder you need to delete unused files most important use images with proper dimesnions and size do not use very high pixlised images in project it will automatically reduce size of your apk

Answer (score 9):

You can compress an APK file (rar, zip), but it has to be decompressed in order to work.

If the apk file to large to distribute you can:

1. Use expansion files: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html
2. Create multiple versions of your apk: http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html (e.g. no hdpi files for ldpi devices)
3. Use [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)

   > ProGuard is a free Java class file shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator,
   >   and preverifier. It detects and removes unused classes, fields,
   >   methods, and attributes. It optimizes bytecode and removes unused
   >   instructions. It renames the remaining classes, fields, and methods
   >   using short meaningless names. Finally, it preverifies the processed
   >   code for Java 6 or higher, or for Java Micro Edition.
   >
   > If you use Eclipse, A default configuration file will automatically be added to your Project. But this default configuration only covers general cases, so you most likely have to edit it for your own needs.
4. Remove unused resources: https://code.google.com/p/android-unused-resources/
5. Optimize your images by using tools like [9patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) and [png optimizers](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/)
6. Remove everything that is only used for debugging purposes (debug classes, or even Log() methods). Also try removing unnecessary .so files

Comment: `You can compress an APK file (rar, zip), but it has to be decompressed in order to work` It would be great if you could share with us how it can be done. If this can be done, it would greatly reduce APK file size.

Comment: @user1995781 This only applies to transfering and/or storing the APK file, e.g. you can put the apk in an archive, offer it as a download on your website and the user has to manually decompress the APK on his device in order to install it.

Comment: You can use [AndResGuard](https://github.com/shwenzhang/AndResGuard) helping you to reduce the api size.

Answer (score 2):

You can [ZipAlign](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html) the signed apk to compress it.

**Usage:**

```
zipalign [-f] [-v] <alignment> infile.apk outfile.apk
```

**Example:**

```
D:\android-sdk\android-sdk\tools>zipalign -f -v 4 "C:\Users\Joisar\Desktop\project_name\appname_signed.apk" "C:\Users\Joisar\Desktop\project_name\appname__zipaligned.apk"
```

**Note:**

Kindly checkout the apk whether it is zipaligned or not by following command, if it's not zipaligned, then do it.

```
zipalign -c -v 4 "C:\Users\Joisar\Desktop\project_name\appname_signed.apk"
```

Comment: Note that if you use eclipse to export your APK's, this is already done.

Comment: I was having same belief but I guess it is not true for all the time.As I have got negative response when I had checked it out for confirmation.

Comment: Hmm, good to know. I guess Eclipse does not really like consistency. Great thing Android Studio is coming up.

Comment: @Mdlc: Yes. But as Studio is still in beta. I'm eagerly waiting for more stable release to rely upon.

Answer (score 2):

#### Find the problem

You can *Analyse APK* from Android Studio. This shows you the various files in their directories and their sizes, both absolute and relative to the whole APK:
[image: menu entry: Analyze APK]

#### [Check for Unused Resources](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html#manuallyRunInspections)

This is the easiest: [image: menu entry: Inspect Code] shows you, among others, the unused resources: [image]

Just remove them from your project.

#### Use Vector Images

[Vector Drawables](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html) provide one sharp image for all resolutions, greatly reducing the size for your graphics. As usually, you can use these for icons etc, but not for Photos. Non-vectorized images can be reduced with [trimage](http://trimage.org/).

#### proguard minify

Add the following to `app/build.gradle` to enable proguard to reduce unused classes from your project:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      shrinkResources true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use .svg format icon set.
2. Compress PNGs.
3. Use only specific libraries of Google Play Services.
4. Use Proguard

   build.gradle

   ```
   android {
       ...
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled true
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. Shrink Resources

   build.gradle

   ```
   android {
       ...
       buildTypes {
           release {
               shrinkResources true
               minifyEnabled true
               ...
           }
       }
   }
   ```