# Apk file size not reducing even after removing drawables

Tags: android, apk

My apk size shot above 5 mb after I added some drawables for screen backgrounds and some icons. In order to reduce the apk size, I deleted some of the drawables from Android Studio by pressing delete on the drawables in the res folder.

But, my apk size is still the same!

Are the drawables being stored in some "Recycle View" concept for their recovery?

Comment: You may try to delete everything from you bin clean the project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce and compress an apk file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380319/how-to-reduce-and-compress-an-apk-file-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Clean build the project, although this is done internally everytime but try yourself too.
Try enabling `proguard` to reduce the apk size, but first put various proguard rules defined by the libraries you use to prevent then from getting removed.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from cleaning the project (by `gradle clean` on the command line),

> [[y]ou can *Analyse APK* from Android Studio. This shows you the various
>   files in their directories and their sizes, both absolute and relative
>   to the whole APK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44344584/1587329): [image: menu entry: Analyze APK]